# Show Popup window on clicking a link in some website's page

Tags: android, popupwindow

I was using some website in my mobile's web browser and when I clicked on a link in website's page, a popup window is showed up like this:

[image]

But when I click on that same link using my application which contains webview ofcourse then it does not show in popup window but in the same webview in which the link is present.

I have tried adding these methods:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
  webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

But they had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

have u tried this on `onCreate()`:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: Why is it needed in onCreate()?